# Problem using ansible facts defined using set_fact

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

So I'm having trouble making use of something I'm setting using set_fact. I'm making use of the community.windows LAPS module to retrieve the password for a given server which is working, but I'm having issues when attempting to then use that password in a quick test.

My playbook is currently,

```
---
- name: LAPS Test Playbook
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    host: myserver
    kdc: dc01.domain.com

  tasks:
  - name: Clear existing Kerberos tokens
    command: kdestroy
    ignore_errors: True

  - name: Get password using simple auth over LDAPS
    set_fact:
      lapsPass: "{{ lookup('laps_password', host, domain=kdc, scheme='ldaps', auth='simple', username='user@DOMAIN.COM', password='mypassword') }}"

  - name: Test output
    debug:
      var: lapsPass

  - name: Get disk facts
    community.windows.win_disk_facts:
    delegate_to: myserver
    vars:
      ansible_user: localadmin
      ansible_password: lapsPass
      ansible_port: 5985
      ansible_connection: winrm
      ansible_connection_transport: basic
      ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
      ansible_winrm_operation_timeout_sec: 600
      ansible_winrm_read_timeout_sec: 660

  - name: Output disk facts
    debug:
      var: ansible_facts.disks[0]
```

The actual password retrieval works, and my Test Output does show me the correct password.

However when I try to use it in the 'Get disk facts' task I get an error,

```
the specified credentials were rejected by the server
```

If I manually put in the password that was displayed by Test output though as a string it works, so I know the actual credentials are correct.
I've also tried using

```
ansible_password: '{{ lapsPass }}'
```

But that returns an error that it's not defined.

So I'm kind of stumped on how I'm supposed to actually use the password to connect to a system once I've successfully retrieved it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. In my Get disk facts task I was able to update the ansible_password to "{{hostvars['localhost']['lapsPass']}}"

So the play becomes,

```
  - name: Get disk facts
    community.windows.win_disk_facts:
    delegate_to: myserver
    vars:
      ansible_user: localadmin
      ansible_password: "{{hostvars['localhost']['lapsPass']}}"
      ansible_port: 5985
      ansible_connection: winrm
      ansible_connection_transport: basic
      ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
      ansible_winrm_operation_timeout_sec: 600
      ansible_winrm_read_timeout_sec: 660
```

Which then allows the task to complete successfully.